# Events in Zepto

Tags: javascript, zepto

I am new to Zepto and I am trying to do something very simple, but it seems I can't do it any way I try. I am trying to bind a function to a click event in Zepto, but the function gets executed even if the event is not fired ...

This is the content of my js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if (!$('.page').hasClass('.current')) {
        $('#home').addClass('current');
        $('.page .content').css('display', 'none');
    $('#home .content').css('display', 'block');
}

$('#menu-trigger').on('click', switchPage('search', 'fade'));

function switchPage(pageID,switchType) {
    oldPageID = '#' + $('.page.current').attr('id');
    newPageID = '#' + pageID;
    if(switchType =='fade') { // Fade Effect
        // $(oldPageID).hide();
        alert('done');
    }
}
});
```

The problem is that the function executes as soon as I reload the html, doesn't wait for the 'click' event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is between specifying which object will be used as the callback, and having the function actually execute and specifying that return value as the callback.

Your code should read:

```
$('#menu-trigger').on('click', switchPage);
function switchPage(pageID,switchType) {
    oldPageID = '#' + $('.page.current').attr('id');
    newPageID = '#' + pageID;
    if(switchType =='fade') { // Fade Effect
        // $(oldPageID).hide();
        alert('done');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you just use `switchPage('search', 'fade')` JS evulates the function and try to set it return value, use this instead.

```
    $('#menu-trigger').on('click', function () { switchPage('search', 'fade') });
```

if you use function with out parameter you can use

```
    $('#menu-trigger').on('click', switchPage );
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for the useful reply! I would NEVER guessed that :)